# Text shown as unicode code points

Tags: gnome, fonts, 20.04, unicode

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 from 19.10, everything is fine. but when I try some of the apps the text is shown in a boxed unicode code points:

The List of apps showing the behavior is:

1. File manager
   [image: File Manager]
2. Settings
   [image: Settings.]
3. GNOME Shell
4. GNOME Tweaks
5. Software manager
6. Rhythmbox
7. Calendar
8. All the utilities applications
9. Calculators

I have tried changing the font from the "Fonts" but it crashes every time.

Comment: I changed the interface text from the GNOME tweaks and the text returned to normal

Answer (score 0):

Just change your fonts for the interface text and the problem will resolve.

But since you can't understand any of the text it is pretty hard to via settings or through  the Fonts app.
So in my case I had GNOME tweaks installed.
You can install it by using https://itsubuntu.com/install-gnome-tweak-tool-on-ubuntu-20-04/ this tutorial.

Open Gnome tweaks.

Now, search for fonts in the search button.
Now select the first result. Remember the "fonts" will have 5 boxed up unicode code points.
Now select the first option that appear in the Fonts sub menu, select whatever Interface Text font you want. Click on the top right button( which is for selecting fonts) .

The text will return to normal everywhere.